# Python - How do I execute function with colon inside parameter by subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, parameters, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use subprocess.open to execute python function with parameters(start and end are all string format), but I'm always getting syntax error as

> "  SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

when I execute the python(python2.7 check.py) , getting the error as below ,

```
import check ; print check .check_output(06:34:00,06:36:00)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
output:
```

my code check.py:

```
def alert(start,end):
   print "start:"+str(start)
   print "end :"+str(end)


start = "06:34:00"
end = "06:36:00"
cmd = "python2.7 -c 'import check ; print check.check_output('"+str(start)+"','"+str(end)+"')' >> /log/debug.log"
print cmd
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()

p_status = p.wait()
print "output:"+str(output)
```

I think the problem is my parameter contain colon(:) , How can I use  colon in function parameter ? Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: you want to execute dates? using `check` module ? or `subprocess` module. Check highlighting in the SO box: you'll see you're not protecting your strings with quotes. Use `"{}".format()` that'll be easier.

Comment: I am using subprocess module

Comment: `import check; check.check_output` ???

Comment: ah....import check and using subprocess.open to execute the function

Comment: I've deleted my answer - your question is too vague to be answered properly. Can you first define what it is that you're trying to achieve because your code is all over the place - for starters, what is the `check.check_output()` function?

Comment: @zwer, start and end is just to print out

Comment: @georgetovrea - I've converted my answer into a working example - it will print out whatever you pass, however where you want to go from there is still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You're not adding quotes to your command so it gets badly interpreted. However, since it's unclear what your functions are and how you want to call them, here's a working example of what you're trying to achieve.

check.py

```
def check_output(*args):
    print("CALLED: check_output({})".format(", ".join([repr(x) for x in args])))
```

It just holds one function and prints out the arguments it was called with. For example, if you were to call it from your shell as:

```
python -c "import check; check.check_output(\"foo\", \"bar\")"
```

It would print to STDOUT:

```
CALLED: check_output('foo', 'bar')
```

So now if you want to call it from another Python script, you can use the `subprocess` module to the same effect, as long as you properly escape your arguments. For example, if you had another `test.py` script with:

```
import subprocess

foo = 'Foo'
bar = 'Bar'

# using 'raw' strings so we don't need to double escape each backslash
cmd = r'python -c "import check; check.check_output(\"' + foo + r'\", \"' + bar + r'\")"'

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

print("OUTPUT: " + out)
```

and run it, you'll get:

```
OUTPUT: CALLED: check_output('Foo', 'Bar')
```

**NOTE** - when constructing your query string like this your variables must also be escaped like we escape the quotations in the example.

You can also let the `subprocess` module to do most of your escaping by formulating your command as:

```
cmd = [
    'python',
    '-c',
    'import check; check.check_output("' + foo + '", "' + bar + '")'
]
```

And you can make it 'safer', or at least easier to manage using `str.format()`:

```
cmd = [
    'python',
    '-c',
    'import check; check.check_output("{}", "{}")'.format(foo, bar)
]
```

Then you don't have to worry about badly escaped characters.

Comment: I have trying as you said , cmd = "python2.7 -c 'import check ; print check.check_output(\\\""+str(start)+"\\\",\\\""+str(end)+"\\\")' >> /log/debug.log"

Comment: still got the error "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character"

Comment: I think the problem is my parameter contain colon(:) , from you example ,if foo = "foo:bar" and bar = "bar:foo" , it's still got the error

Comment: @georgetovrea - well, you have to escape all special characters, the 'self-constructed' call escapes only the quotations. Use the later example (storing separate arguments in a list) and let the `subprocess` module do your escaping. For example, if you set `foo = 'Foo:Foo'` it will print `OUTPUT: CALLED: check_output('Foo:Foo', 'Bar')` just fine.